# How do I assign the text of HTML Elements to a XSLT Variable?

Tags: html, xslt-2.0

I want to create a dynamic XSLT Variable. It should fetch the content of the first td of each row, something like this:

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>not Important</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>not Important</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>not Important</td></tr>
```

My XSL:Variable looks something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="name" select="concat('out/',//td[1]/text(),'.html')"/>
```

I want to use the elements content (in my Case 1, 2, 3) to create new Html Files and name them accordingly:

```
<xsl:result-document href="{$name}">
```

Result:
1.html
2.html
3.html

With my current XSL:Variable Oxygen would give me that error:
A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the second argument of concat()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to map each row to a result document then I suggest to write a template

`<xsl:template match="tr">
  <xsl:result-document href="out{td[1]}.html">
     ...
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>`

then make sure there is an `apply-templates` for the parent table that makes sure the `tr` elementd are processed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you got there is, that the concat()-function can put strings together, but your statement "//td[1]/text" does indeed select 3 strings, not just one.

A way to generate these 3 filenames would be iterating over the tr-nodes and selecting the first td-node in each of them:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//tr">
    <xsl:variable name="justOneNameAtATime"
        select="concat('out/',.//td[1]/text(),'.html')" />
    <!-- do whatever you want with the single name, e.g.: -->
    <xsl:result-document href="{$name}">
</xsl:for-each>
```

Notice the dot in front of the "//", meaning that the search for "td"-nodes will only take place in the current context (= in the "tr"-node).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. I understand the logic yet Oxygen would still give me the error after adding the dot :/

Comment: Even in a for-each loop? The loop is essentially necessary for things to work.